# tmux: bind key with asking

Tags: tmux

is there a way to bind a key and have tmux ask for an option? I'd like to have a bind key for resize-pane where tmux asks me how many lines/columns I want to resize.
Alternative would be to have a key bind that shows the command and not executes, but lets me edit it before I execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`choose-prompt` is provided for this purpose. It takes `-p` a comma-separated list of prompts, and a final command template in which `%1` will be replaced by the first reply, etc. For example,

```
bind-key r  command-prompt -p "x: ,y: " "resize-pane -x %1 -y %2"
```